# Arcgis JS API 4.x how to localize?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm looking for ways to customize built in widgets, but couldn't find anything in version 4.x.

In version 3.x you can do it in following way as mentioned in doc https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/localization.html:

```
var map;
require(["esri/map", "dojo/i18n!esri/nls/jsapi", "dojo/domReady!"],
  function(Map, bundle) {
    bundle.widgets.homeButton.home.title = 'Эзэмшлийн газар'
  }
);
```

But in version 4.x, there's only way to customize DOJO text, not arcgis:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/localization/index.html

Comment: digz6666: In version 4.x, this type of localization isn't implemented yet. But it is planned for a future 4.x release.

Answer (score 3):

I think, theoretically, it is possible to `npm install` JS API from Esri GitHub repository, and before making a Custom Build of JS API edit strings in localization files — they are situated in t9n folders.

https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-js-api/tree/4master

Second approach, for widgets, is to create your own view and use your own localization and UI components. You can use ViewModels of the widgets from JS API accordingly.